# _tprintf with Unicode characters in a console app

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode, console-application

I'm doing this simple output from a Unicode-built console application (using C++ and Visual Studio 2008). This code is intended to run on Windows:

```
_tprintf(L"Some sample string\n");
```

Everything works fine. But if I add an non-ASCII character in there:

```
_tprintf(L"Some sample € string\n");
```

what gets output to the console is everything until that character:

> Some sample

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It is because your console is not capable of displaying that character.  The conversion from Unicode to the 8-bit code page fails there and that truncates the string.  The default code page for a console is normally 437, the olden IBM PC code page, a machine that was designed before Europe adopted its new currency.  You'll have to switch the console to another encoding that does have the character, SetConsoleOutputCP().

Comment: I just tried calling `SetConsoleOutputCP(1200);` before that call and nothing changed.

Comment: give `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT);` a try

Comment: @Cubbi: You got it. Do you want to post it as a separate answer and I'll mark it as a solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, windows console does not process wide characters. Probably the simplest way to enable that functionality is to call `_setmode`:

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT);
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw4k6df8.aspx) for the required includes, usage examples, and other available modes.