# Using tprintf for TCHAR argv[0] and getting question marks

Tags: c++, visual-studio

It's been awhile (10+ years) since I've developed in C++. I am trying to accept a value via command line and pass it along to a class constructor.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <windows.h>
    #include "WinFolderMonitor.h"
#elif __APPLE__
#elif __linux__
#elif __unix__
#endif

int main(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Usage: %s <dir>\n"), argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

#ifdef _WIN32
    WinFolderMonitor* folderMonitor = new WinFolderMonitor(argv[1]);
#endif

    folderMonitor->WatchDirectory();

    return 0;
}
```

However, the output I am getting is not as expected. Rather, I am receiving a bunch of question marks, which I would normally attribute to some encoding issue but I believe that I've set up the project correctly to mitigate that.

```
C:\SVN\monitor.exe
Usage: ?????????e????? <dir>
```

From my understanding, I should be seeing the application filename. But I am getting a whole bunch of question marks. I have setup my project to use "Unicode" within Visual Studio.

Comment: I'd say you're obviously getting a mismatch between ASCII and Unicode. `tprintf` is controlled by `_MBCS`, `_UNICODE` and `_unicode`. Double check those #defines.

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443168/tprintf-with-unicode-characters-in-a-console-app

Comment: All that `tchar` nonsense is there to support Windows 95. Since that's now irrelevant, just write code assuming Unicode.

Comment: @AlanStokes Really? So stick to using `wchar_t`?

Comment: Yes. As an extra benefit, by using standard facilities your code becomes inherently more portable.

Comment: @AlanStokes I've refactored the remaining code that was using TCHAR. Still getting funky ASCII text in the command prompt UNLESS I use the Windows-specific `_tmain` function. I've checked and double checked my project properties and it is in fact set to Unicode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `_tmain` instead `main`. If UNICODE is defined, `_tmain` becomes a macro for `wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])`

See also [msdn:main](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh.aspx)

```
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Usage: %s <dir>\n"), argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is usually for homework purposes. There is no point to make this ANSI compatible unless you are also targeting Windows 98. Otherwise you can use UNICODE only version, for example `const wchar_t *text = L"text";` etc.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. What happens when I need to port this over to Linux? I guess that has been my main concern from the start, and since `wmain` seems to be specific to VS / Windows, there will be some lack of portability. What would I do to still support `wchar_t` in a Linux environment using `main`?

Comment: `_tmain`, `_printf`, `_tcscpy_s` etc. are Microsoft macros defined in `"tchar.h"`. This can get very messy. You should use C++ functions `std::string` for Linux/UTF8/ANSI, and `std::wstring` for Windows UTF16. Then you can make your own macro `tstring` to use one or the other, depending on the system. Do a search on `TCHAR`+`tstring`. Avoid using C-style functions such as `strcpy`